# Is Modernizr still necessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bundling-and-minification, modernizr

I'm migrating to Bootstrap 5.0.2 and cleaning up the bundling for optimization. With deprecated support for various older browser versions and the fact that Modernizr.js hasn't been updated since 2017, is this line even still necessary?

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\" async></script>", "~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Comment: The Modernizr bundle included in the tools may be out of date, but the library itself is [still receiving updates](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/releases). The last release was 3 months ago, which, while not exactly recent in web development terms, is certainly more recent than 2017. (I can't voice an opinion as to whether it's necessary or not.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment on Modernizr still receiving updates. I've decided to pull it for now and and it looks like it's a different world with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is browsers that does not support all HTML5 and CSS3 features.
Also more than users, Older versions of a browser are still in use,
To display your website properly in users' old browsers, should  of [Modernizr.js](https://modernizr.com/) use

Comment: It should be noted that bootstrap 5 already abandons support of IE10 and IE11, just in terms of css as well. So even using Modernizer would not work in legacy browsers, because even a website with no js code will break.

Comment: I'm leaving it out especially as I decided to go all the way and move to ASP.NET Core MVC too.

Answer (score 1):

This is more project-specific question.

Maybe it's not necessary at all, thus complete waste of time & efforts when you know who exactly is going to use your work (for example, a closed group of clients with modern hardware and operating systems).

**Besides that, it is absolutely wise decision to use `Modernizr`.**

Ask yourself:

- do you / how do you know you can use some modern (or even not-so-modern) browser feature without leaving a share of your users with nothing
- can you afford angry user because nothing happens when he clicks on "Start application" or shaming layout failure happens

Case: you are okay with testing and providing fallback but `Modernizr` seems to you like overkill. You want just `"feature" in document.body` simple test.

- is it a good decision to reinvent a wheel of feature testing even if it seems to you that what you are up to is a simple true/false test. Remember, `Modernizr` often goes way beyond simple tests, because, well, that's precisely what it is made for.

Comment: If developers keep accomodating legacy browsers and legacy systems then these systems will never be updated. Modernizr was a good idea 10 years ago, the fact it's still around is more a sign of how much internet users do not update their systems, so to start **NOT** using Modernizr gradually pushes web browser users to actually update their systems.

Comment: I totally agree with Martin.  However, some of us work in a corporate environment (health insurance) and our external users (doctor's offices and government) are notorious for being slow to upgrade.  We cannot simply say "sorry about your luck, upgrade your systems then get back to us" because we end up with FAXES that must be manually entered on our end, or we run afoul of government contract requirements.